# При попытке прочитать значение с клавиатуры происходит java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java

Выполняю следующий код:

```
package ru.itsjava.algorythmes;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = reader();
        int b = reader();
    }

    public static int reader(){
        System.out.print("Enter the number: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int value = scan.nextInt();
        scan.close();
        return value;
    }
}
```

Во время выполнения он читает клавиатуру и присваивает первой переменной значение. Но при повторном вызове reader() происходит ошибка. При этом исключение NoSuchElementException  не передаёт сообщений (нет двоеточия с каким-то комментарием).
По-идее переменная scan должна существовать только внутри reader() и исчезать после завершения метода. Так что для меня не совсем очевидно почему при повторном вызове метода происходит исключение. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Просто интересно что происходит именно в таком случае.

Comment: `scan.close();` это зачем?

Comment: Я не пишу на java, но мне кажется, когда вы создаете Сканер и потом его закрываете, он закрывает и `System.in`, потому второе чтение не срабатывает. Наверное лучше один раз создать сканер и везде его переиспользовать.

Comment: При закрытии сканера происходит закрытие стрима. Если на закрытом стриме создать сканер и попробовать что-то прочитать, то вылетит `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: @tym32167 scan.close() чтобы поток закрыть и он не оставался открытым после вызова метода.

Comment: @learp я-то рассчитывал, что переменная scan существует только во время выполнения метода и уничтожается в конце. А значит должно быть можно объявить и уничтожить её снова. Может быть эта переменная живёт дольше потому, что метод static?

Answer (score 0):

@Red Circle, для меня тоже странно, но в вашем случае именно scan.close(); является причиной исключения. Закомментируйте и все работает нормально.
Я могу вам предложить проверенный в работе и удобный метод получения целых чисел в заданном диапазоне из консоли:

```
public static int readerIntFromInterval(int a, int b) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userInput;
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Введите целое "
                + "число в диапазоне [" + a + " .. " + b + "]: ");
        if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
            userInput = scan.nextInt();
            if (userInput >= a && userInput <= b) break;
            else
                System.out.println("Не соответствует условиям ввода! ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Не соответствует условиям ввода! ");
            scan.nextLine();
        }
    }
    scan.close();
    System.out.println("Введено число: " + userInput);
    return userInput;
}
```

И хотя здесь тоже присутствует scan.close(), но код работает исправно.

Comment: Наврала... Здесь тоже при повторном вводе вылетает ошибка (((